Space trees that use sunlight
Book about trees that have a bubble around then and exist in space, get chemicals from gas planets, and use sunlight

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this book?  Was it a hardcover, paperback, or e-book?  Do you remember the cover art?

Maybe something here? https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TreeVessel

"get chemicals from gas [planets], and use sunlight" Isn't that technically all trees?

The prototypical book about space trees is Niven's The Integral Trees (1984).

The titular trees float in the "Smoke Ring," the central part of a gas torus surrounding a neutron star ("Levoy's Star" or "Voy").  The gas is drawn from a gas giant ("Goldblatt's World" or "Gold) in close orbit around the neutron star.
Quoting from Wikipedia:

No "ground" exists in the Smoke Ring; it consists entirely of sky. Furthermore, the Smoke Ring is in orbit and therefore in free fall: there is no "up" or "down". Most animals have trilateral symmetry that allows them to see in all directions. The majority of Smoke Ring animals have evolved to fly on at least an occasional basis—even the fish. The Smoke Ring contains numerous "ponds", globs of water of various sizes which float free like everything else. While there are aquatic and amphibious animals in the Smoke Ring that live the majority of their lives in such ponds, these animals may find their habitat unsuitable at any moment. Whether their home pond drifts too far out of the habitable center of the Smoke Ring and into the gas torus, becomes too large and breaks up due to tidal forces, or impacts a large object such as an integral tree, aquatic animals must be able to propel themselves through the air sometimes in order to find a new place to live.
Most plants in the Smoke Ring are quite fragile because they do not need to support their own weight. A notable exception to this rule are the eponymous Integral Trees, which can grow up to 100 kilometers long. Tidal locking causes them to be radially oriented, with one end pointing in toward Voy while the other points toward space. The ends of the tree feel a tidal force of up to 1⁄5 g0 on the largest trees. Each end of a tree is a green, leafy tuft.


And sequel, The Smoke Ring.

It's unusual to see a cover which looks like the artist has actually read the content: that one's outstanding.

@MarkMorganLloyd That's because it's a Whelan cover; his covers were always the best.
